# How to Quickly Switch Between High and Low Brightness Settings on a Dell U3421WE Monitor?

Tags: display, brightness, dell

I'm currently using a Dell U3421WE monitor on macOS 14.2.1 with Apple M2 Max and facing a unique challenge due to my living situation. My apartment lacks curtains, resulting in very bright natural light during the day and much lower light levels at night. To adapt to these conditions, I need to frequently switch my monitor's brightness settings: from very high during the day to combat the natural light, to very low at night to be comfortable for my eyes.

I'm seeking a convenient method to switch between these two brightness settings without having to manually adjust them through the monitor's physical buttons or on-screen display each time. Ideally, I'm looking for a software solution or a shortcut that can toggle between two preset brightness levels. I haven't found specific features or software that supports this functionality for the Dell U3421WE.

Does anyone have recommendations on how I might achieve this? Are there any third-party applications or hidden features that I might not be aware of that could facilitate this process?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If the on-screen (Mac) control works it would only be a matter of 2 seconds to change brightness.  That is what I do when I need to change brightness on my laptop.

Comment: Would you please let me know more details? I am all new to this.

Comment: "I am all new to this"... To what exactly? *Member for 11 years, 3 months*

Comment: @ChanganAuto I mean to the monitor. The only thing I know is to plug on it to my mac with a USB-C cable. And I don't know how to save settings or use software to set it.

Comment: You led me to think there was a manual brightness control. If there is not such a thing, then I do not know how you would invent a control in software.